# How to solve the self-crash problem of running multiple pyqt or pyqtgraph drawing components?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

[image]

I designed the interface, and the custom component tried to output multiple drawing components, and the program crashed after a while.

The program probably consists of the following:`ble. Py` reads the bluetooth values temporarily holding the EMG array. `main_plot.py` instantiates the Show_EMG plotting class and outputs the Show_EMG plotting class reading the Bluetooth values of `ble.PY`

The program crashed itself without reporting any errors, I tried to output errors at different terminals.

ERROR MESSAGE:
[image]

[image]

CMD:
[image]

pyqtgraph Component Code(Show_EMG.py):

```
import ble
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtCore

class Plot_Show(object):
    '''
    Form,y,x,data,length = 1800, width = 250, high = 120, text = "sEMG Voltage"
    '''
    def __init__(self,Form,y,x,data,text=""):
        # length = 1800, width = 250, high = 120, text = "sEMG Voltage"
        self.Form=Form
        self.y=y
        self.x=x
        self.data=ble.EMG[data]
        self.length=1800
        if(text==""):
            self.test="sEMG Voltage"
        else:
            self.text = text
        self.graphicsView = PlotWidget(self.Form)
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.y, self.x, 250, 120))
        self.graphicsView.hideButtons()
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName(self.text)


        self.graphicsView.setLabel(axis="left",text=self.text)
        self.graphicsView.setLabel(axis='bottom',text='Time')
        self.graphicsView.setMouseEnabled(x=False,y=False)
        self.graphicsView.setAntialiasing(True)
        self.graphicsView.setMenuEnabled(False)
        self.graphicsView.hideButtons()
        self.data1 = np.zeros(self.length)
        self.curve1 = self.graphicsView.plot(self.data1)
        self.ptr1 = 0

        def update1():
            global data1, ptr1
            self.graphicsView.setRange(xRange=[self.ptr1,self.ptr1+self.length],yRange=[5,550],padding=0)
            self.data1[:-1] = self.data1[1:]  # shift data in the array one sample left

            self.data1[-1] = self.data

            self.ptr1 += 1
            self.curve1.setData(self.data1)
            self.curve1.setPos(self.ptr1, 0)

        self.timer = pg.QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(update1)
        self.timer.start(10)
```

main_plot.py Code:

```py
import ble
import sys

import Show_EMG
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import threading

class Ui_Form(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def setupUi(self, Form,**kwargs):
        Form.resize(820, 454)
        Form.setObjectName("Form")

                Show_EMG.Plot_Show(Form=Form, y=10, x=10, data=0, text="sEMG2 Voltage")
        Show_EMG.Plot_Show(Form=Form, y=10, x=140, data=1, text="sEMG2 Voltage")
        Show_EMG.Plot_Show(Form=Form, y=10, x=270, data=2, text="sEMG3 Voltage")
        Show_EMG.Plot_Show(Form=Form, y=280, x=10, data=3, text="sEMG4 Voltage")
        Show_EMG.Plot_Show(Form=Form, y=280, x=140, data=4, text="sEMG5 Voltage")
        Show_EMG.Plot_Show(Form=Form, y=280, x=270, data=5, text="sEMG6 Voltage")
        Show_EMG.Plot_Show(Form=Form, y=550, x=10, data=0, text="sEMG7 Voltage")
        Show_EMG.Plot_Show(Form=Form, y=550, x=140, data=0, text="sEMG8 Voltage")

        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 270, 261, 121))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 410, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "开始记录"))
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread_main=threading.Thread(target=main)
    thread_main.start()
    thread_ble=threading.Thread(target=ble.ble)
    thread_ble.start()
```

Ble.EMG array default temporarily to:`[200.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]`

More Ble Code detail:
https://gist.github.com/allrobot/1547447f313942f278118cb2e569f59f

I tried to add threads in main_plot.py, but the program still crashes itself...

Perhaps QTimer should be the cause of the problem?

How can I change the code to solve the self-crash problem?I need to fix the custom component classes, but I am novice to PyQT, you have any suggestions?

Comment: did you run in console to see error messages? Without error message we have no clue what can make problem

Comment: @furas Sorry, I forget error messages. It has now been replenished.

Comment: threading needs function's name without `()` and later it will use `()` to run it. But you use instaces of class and this makes problem. Instance of class is not a function.

Comment: frankly I don't understand why you want to use threading. All what you could use as `target=` in `threading` is `update1` from `Plot_Show` but it already uses `QTimer` to run it. And `QTimer` already uses `threading` for this.

Comment: @furas Sorry, I'm not very good at Python. Problem seems to be the from the QTimer? Should I use the thread target=xxx.update1()?

Comment: no - problem is because you use `threading` in wrong way. you can't use `target=Plot_Show()` beause `Plot_Show()` is `instance of class` but `targer=` need `function's name`, And frankly you don't even needs `threading` because you already use `QTimer`

Comment: And you have common mistake in all `target=` - it needs function's name without `()` - like `target=main` instead of `target=main()`. And `target=ble.ble` instead of `target=ble.ble()`

Comment: @furas OK. I discarded the Thread usage. But Pycharm did not report any errors after the program in the first GIF crashed itself

Comment: if program crashed then maybe it crashed also PyCharm code and it couldn't report it. Test code directly in console/terminal.

Comment: @furas I have found that CMD does not self-crash when running the py file, but its drawing is inconsistent, as shown in the fourth figure.

Comment: @C.SH.K Most IDEs are not able to show PyQt errors, nor display the full traceback, always remember to try the program in shell/prompt when you don't understand what's happening. Besides, you should ***NEVER*** use threading for the main Qt Application, as it **must** run in the main thread, and UI elements are **not** thread-safe. Trying to do so might even result in fatal crashes, sometimes even without any traceback at all.

Comment: @musicamante Yes, You're right. I solved the problem today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know (all) GUIs shouldn't run in separated thread.

But main problem which I had with code is that some elements in PyQt don't work if they are not assigned to global or class variables.

And when `Plot` is not assigned to variable then its `QTimer` doesn't work for me.

So I put all Plot on list and now all QTimers (without special threads) works for me.

```
        self.plots = [
            PlotShow(...),
            PlotShow(...),
            PlotShow(...),
            # ...
        ]
```

---

Full working code.

I used class `ble` to simulate module `ble.py` and to have all code in one file (for tests).

I made also few small changes: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

```
#import ble
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import pyqtgraph as pg   # pg.PlotWidget
import numpy as np
import threading


class ble:
    ''' Simulate module `ble.py` '''
    
    EMG = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    
    def ble():
        import math
        import random
        import time

        counter = 0
        
        while True:
        
            for i in range(10):
            
                if i in (0, 4, 8):
                    ble.EMG[i] = random.randint(0, 550)
                elif i in (1, 5, 6):
                    ble.EMG[i] = random.randint(150, 250)
                else:
                    ble.EMG[i] = 200 + math.sin(math.radians(counter//i)) * 200
            
            counter += 1
            time.sleep(0.1)
    
class PlotShow():  # PE8: `CamelNames` for classes
    '''
    form, y, x, data, length=1800, width=250, high=120, text="sEMG Voltage"
    '''
    def __init__(self, form, y, x, data_number, text=""):   # PEP8: spaces after commans `,`
        self.form = form   # PE8: `lower_case_names` for variables
        self.y = y
        self.x = x
        self.data_number = data_number
        self.length = 1800

        self.data = np.zeros(self.length)
        self.ptr  = 0
        
        if not text:
            self.test="sEMG Voltage"
        else:
            self.text = text
        
        self.initUI()

        #print('start:', self.text)
        self.timer = pg.QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_plot)
        self.timer.start(10)


    def initUI(self):
        self.graphicsView = pg.PlotWidget(self.form)

        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.y, self.x, 250, 120))
        self.graphicsView.hideButtons()
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName(self.text)

        self.graphicsView.setLabel(axis="left",text=self.text)
        self.graphicsView.setLabel(axis='bottom',text='Time')
        self.graphicsView.setMouseEnabled(x=False,y=False)
        self.graphicsView.setAntialiasing(True)
        self.graphicsView.setMenuEnabled(False)
        self.graphicsView.hideButtons()
        
        self.curve = self.graphicsView.plot(self.data)

    def update_plot(self):
        #print('update:', self.text)
        
        self.data[:-1] = self.data[1:]  # shift data in the array one sample left
        self.data[-1]  = ble.EMG[self.data_number]

        self.ptr += 1

        self.curve.setData(self.data)
        self.curve.setPos(self.ptr, 0)
        self.graphicsView.setRange(xRange=[self.ptr, self.ptr+self.length], yRange=[5, 550], padding=0)  # PEP8: spaces after commans `,`

        
class UIForm():  # PE8: `CamelNames` for classes

    def setupUI(self, form, **kwargs):
        form.resize(820, 454)
        form.setObjectName("Form")

        self.plots = [
            PlotShow(form=form, y=10,  x=10,  data_number=0, text="sEMG1 Voltage"),
            PlotShow(form=form, y=10,  x=140, data_number=1, text="sEMG2 Voltage"),
            PlotShow(form=form, y=10,  x=270, data_number=2, text="sEMG3 Voltage"),
            PlotShow(form=form, y=280, x=10,  data_number=3, text="sEMG4 Voltage"),
            PlotShow(form=form, y=280, x=140, data_number=4, text="sEMG5 Voltage"),
            PlotShow(form=form, y=280, x=270, data_number=5, text="sEMG6 Voltage"),
            PlotShow(form=form, y=550, x=10,  data_number=6, text="sEMG7 Voltage"),
            PlotShow(form=form, y=550, x=140, data_number=7, text="sEMG8 Voltage"),
            PlotShow(form=form, y=550, x=270, data_number=8, text="sEMG9 Voltage"),
        ]
        
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(form)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 270, 261, 121))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 410, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(form)
        
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(form)

    def retranslateUi(self, form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "开始记录"))
        form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    form = QtWidgets.QWidget()  # PE8: `lower_case_names` for variables
    ui = UIForm()
    ui.setupUI(form)
    form.show()
    app.exec()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # better start before GUI to create all needed variables and values
    thread_ble = threading.Thread(target=ble.ble)
    thread_ble.start()
    
    #thread_main = threading.Thread(target=main)
    #thread_main.start()
    #input() # keep running program when GUI runs in thread
    
    # GUI rather shouldn't run in separated thread
    main()
```

[image]

Frankly, if all plots get data from the same source and in the same time then you could use one QTimer to run all `update1` in all plots - but this timer should be in `UIForm` instead of `PlotShow`

---

**EDIT:**

Version which use only one `QTimer` in `UIForm` to execute `update_plot()` for all plots on list `self.plots`.

```
#import ble
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import pyqtgraph as pg   # pg.PlotWidget
import numpy as np
import threading


class ble:
    ''' Simulate module `ble.py` '''
    
    EMG = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    
    def ble():
        import math
        import random
        import time

        counter = 0
        
        while True:
        
            for i in range(10):
            
                if i in (0, 4, 8):
                    ble.EMG[i] = random.randint(0, 550)
                elif i in (1, 5, 6):
                    ble.EMG[i] = random.randint(150, 250)
                else:
                    ble.EMG[i] = 200 + math.sin(math.radians(counter//i)) * 200
            
            counter += 1
            time.sleep(0.1)
    
class PlotShow():  # PE8: `CamelNames` for classes
    '''
    form, y, x, data, length=1800, width=250, high=120, text="sEMG Voltage"
    '''
    def __init__(self, form, y, x, data_number, text=""):   # PEP8: spaces after commans `,`
        self.form = form   # PE8: `lower_case_names` for variables
        self.y = y
        self.x = x
        self.data_number = data_number
        self.length = 1800

        self.data = np.zeros(self.length)
        self.ptr  = 0
        
        if not text:
            self.test="sEMG Voltage"
        else:
            self.text = text
        
        self.initUI()

        #print('start:', self.text)
        #self.timer = pg.QtCore.QTimer()
        #self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_plot)
        #self.timer.start(10)


    def initUI(self):
        self.graphicsView = pg.PlotWidget(self.form)

        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.y, self.x, 250, 120))
        self.graphicsView.hideButtons()
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName(self.text)

        self.graphicsView.setLabel(axis="left",text=self.text)
        self.graphicsView.setLabel(axis='bottom',text='Time')
        self.graphicsView.setMouseEnabled(x=False,y=False)
        self.graphicsView.setAntialiasing(True)
        self.graphicsView.setMenuEnabled(False)
        self.graphicsView.hideButtons()
        
        self.curve = self.graphicsView.plot(self.data)

    def update_plot(self):
        #print('update:', self.text)
        
        self.data[:-1] = self.data[1:]  # shift data in the array one sample left
        self.data[-1]  = ble.EMG[self.data_number]

        self.ptr += 1

        self.curve.setData(self.data)
        self.curve.setPos(self.ptr, 0)
        self.graphicsView.setRange(xRange=[self.ptr, self.ptr+self.length], yRange=[5, 550], padding=0)  # PEP8: spaces after commans `,`

        
class UIForm():  # PE8: `CamelNames` for classes

    def setupUI(self, form, **kwargs):
        form.resize(820, 454)
        form.setObjectName("Form")

        self.plots = [
            PlotShow(form=form, y=10,  x=10,  data_number=0, text="sEMG1 Voltage"),
            PlotShow(form=form, y=10,  x=140, data_number=1, text="sEMG2 Voltage"),
            PlotShow(form=form, y=10,  x=270, data_number=2, text="sEMG3 Voltage"),
            PlotShow(form=form, y=280, x=10,  data_number=3, text="sEMG4 Voltage"),
            PlotShow(form=form, y=280, x=140, data_number=4, text="sEMG5 Voltage"),
            PlotShow(form=form, y=280, x=270, data_number=5, text="sEMG6 Voltage"),
            PlotShow(form=form, y=550, x=10,  data_number=6, text="sEMG7 Voltage"),
            PlotShow(form=form, y=550, x=140, data_number=7, text="sEMG8 Voltage"),
            PlotShow(form=form, y=550, x=270, data_number=8, text="sEMG9 Voltage"),
        ]
        
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(form)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 270, 261, 121))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 410, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(form)
        
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(form)

        self.timer = pg.QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_all_plots)
        self.timer.start(10)
        
    def update_all_plots(self):
        for plot in self.plots:
            plot.update_plot()
        
    def retranslateUi(self, form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "开始记录"))
        form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    form = QtWidgets.QWidget()  # PE8: `lower_case_names` for variables
    ui = UIForm()
    ui.setupUI(form)
    form.show()
    app.exec()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # better start before GUI to create all needed variables and values
    thread_ble = threading.Thread(target=ble.ble)
    thread_ble.start()
    
    #thread_main = threading.Thread(target=main)
    #thread_main.start()
    #input() # keep running program when GUI runs in thread
    
    # GUI rather shouldn't run in separated thread
    main()
```

Comment: Yes, all plots get data from the same source.

Comment: I added code which uses one `QTimer` (in `UIForm`) to execute `update_plot` for all plots on list `self.plots`

Comment: You are a hero. I was going to solve this problem by myself, but you did it for me

Answer (score 0):

Thank @furas and @musicamante suggests, the problem is solved.

The bug is surprisingly simple.

I set the refresh rate too fast. Because I setting `self.timer.start(10)` in the custom component class, So the program crashes itself.It only need setting `self.timer.start(100)`, the program can working...